# Update sentence with subquery on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, subquery

I have the following sentence, that returns the error

> Unknown column targets.ID_TARGET in where clause

and I can't find any solution. Could you guys help?
The proposal is update 'sw_automatic' for each row with the value that th subquery provides (0 or 1)

```
update bt_pry_targets targets
set targets.sw_automatic = (
(
SELECT (CASE WHEN Task.ID_TP_TASKS_GROUPS = 694 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END) AS TYPE_TASK, 
                    Task.ID_TASK FROM bt_tasks AS Task
                    INNER JOIN bt_pry_cmp_workflows AS BtCmpWorkflows ON (Task.ID_PRY_CMP_WORKFLOW = BtCmpWorkflows.ID_PRY_CMP_WORKFLOW)
                    INNER JOIN bt_pry_components AS PryComponent ON (PryComponent.ID_PRY_COMPONENT = BtCmpWorkflows.ID_PRY_COMPONENT )
                    INNER JOIN bt_components AS Component ON (PryComponent.ID_COMPONENT = Component.ID_COMPONENT)
                    INNER JOIN bt_pry_targets AS PryTarget ON (PryComponent.ID_TARGET = PryTarget.ID_TARGET)
                    INNER JOIN bt_flows AS Flows ON (Flows.ID_FLOW = Task.ID_FLOW) 
                    WHERE Flows.SW_END_DEPENDENCE = 1
                    AND PryTarget.ID_TARGET = targets.ID_TARGET
                    GROUP BY Task.ID_TASK) )
where targets.sw_automatic is null;
```

Comment: . . Your code doesn't work.  I would suggest that you ask a question describing the problem what you want to accomplish; provide sample data and desired results.  Simplify the question, because you can address the question with probably only 2 or 3 tables.  Then it is feasible for someone to help you.

Comment: We can't see your schema so we don't know if  targets.ID_TARGET actually exists of if you spelled it incorrectly or some other issue.

Comment: I simplified the query. What I want to achieve is, update each row of tha table bt_pry_targets with the value provided by the subquery. ID_TARGET is the PK of the table

Comment: Your subquery is selecting two columns, `TYPE_TASK` and `ID_TASK`. The `SET` will fail. Does `ID_TARGET` exist in the `bt_pry_targets` table? Rather than a subquery, it would probably be easier — and more efficient for the query engine — to rewrite this query to use standard `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: As mentioned previously, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

In you subquery  the column targets.ID_TARGET in not visible

so you could try using you subquery as a join table for updated

```
    update bt_pry_targets targets
    inner join  (
    SELECT (CASE WHEN Task.ID_TP_TASKS_GROUPS = 694 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END) AS TYPE_TASK, 
                        Task.ID_TASK FROM bt_tasks AS Task
                        INNER JOIN bt_pry_cmp_workflows AS BtCmpWorkflows ON (Task.ID_PRY_CMP_WORKFLOW = BtCmpWorkflows.ID_PRY_CMP_WORKFLOW)
                        INNER JOIN bt_pry_components AS PryComponent ON (PryComponent.ID_PRY_COMPONENT = BtCmpWorkflows.ID_PRY_COMPONENT )
                        INNER JOIN bt_components AS Component ON (PryComponent.ID_COMPONENT = Component.ID_COMPONENT)
                        INNER JOIN bt_pry_targets AS PryTarget ON (PryComponent.ID_TARGET = PryTarget.ID_TARGET)
                        INNER JOIN bt_flows AS Flows ON (Flows.ID_FLOW = Task.ID_FLOW) 
                        WHERE Flows.SW_END_DEPENDENCE = 1
                        AND PryTarget.ID_TARGET = targets.ID_TARGET
                        GROUP BY Task.ID_TASK
    ) t on t.PryTarget = targets.ID_TARGET 
        AND targets.sw_automatic is null
    set targets.sw_automatic = t.TYPE_TASK
```